# Import Mysql functions file on laravel 5 seeder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I have some functions for Mysql on test.sql file.
 When I import this file on mysql from phpmyadmin everything is ok.
 But I want import it dynamically from Laravel Seeder. When I use this on my seeder, does not import it on my Mysql.

```
public function run()
 {
    DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(base_path().'/myfolder/test.sql'));
 }
```

When I add `insert` command on test.sql work correctly like this

```
 INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `family`) VALUES(1, 'test', 'test2');
```

But When I use this command dose not work

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `__mydiv`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `__mydiv`(`a` int, `b` int) 
RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN
   return FLOOR(a / b);
END;
```

Comment: make a try with this `DB::unprepared(DB::raw(file_get_contents(base_path().'/myfolder/test.sql')));`

Comment: `$json = File::get("myfolder/test.sql");` 

I ever imported json file from Laravel Seeder, but I never import sql file. I think maybe that will be same

Comment: I edit my post...